# hcitool le scan Doesn't work and kills Bluetooth-Module

Tags: networking, bluetooth, shutdown, restart

I tried to use the hcitool via terminal to find my BLE-Device i am working on.
I am programming a micrcontroller with custom services and characteristics. I want to scan for BLE-devices to find their ble-adress. I can connect to my device because i have set an static adress. But when i want to connect to devices i don't know the adress of it would be nice to scan for them before. My Problem is when i type in

```
sudo hcitool lescan
```

my terminal stops working and i can't use any commands anymore. When i type `exit` or something similar it doesn't do anything anymore. Also i can't use my bluetooth anymore without shut down and restart my computer. It is not enough to "restart" via restart-button. I have to shut down and manually restart my system to use my bluetooth module again. Is there a solution? I can connect to my device via gatttool `sudo gatttool -b 01:01:01:01:01:01 -I` and read/write/discover services and characteristics.